# Prove that: $j_0(\sqrt{x^2-2xt})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{t^n}{n!}j_n(x)$ (Bessel Functions)

Tags: taylor-expansion, special-functions, bessel-functions

Prove that:

$j_0(\sqrt{x^2-2xt})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{t^n}{n!}j_n(x)$

the result can be obtained by applying the Taylor expansion for
a conveniently chosen function, with appropriate changes of variable, and the
help from

$j_n(x)=(-1)^nx^n\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\dfrac{d}{dx} \right)^n\left( \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} \right)$

I think it can be obtained from the generating function for spherical Bessel functions, but I can't find a way to relate it.

Answer (score 1):

The (exponential) generating function of the spherical Bessel functions of the first kind is
$$
\frac{\cos\left(\sqrt{x^2-2xt}\right)}{x} = \sum \limits_{m=0}^\infty \frac{t^m}{m!} \operatorname{j}_{m-1}(x) \, .
$$
Taking the derivative with respect to $t$ we obtain
\begin{align}
\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} \operatorname{j}_n(x) &= \sum \limits_{m=1}^\infty \frac{t^{m-1}}{(m-1)!} \operatorname{j}_{m-1}(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \sum \limits_{m=0}^\infty \frac{t^m}{m!} \operatorname{j}_{m-1}(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\cos\left(\sqrt{x^2-2xt}\right)}{x} \\
&= \frac{\sin\left(\sqrt{x^2-2xt}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-2xt}} = \operatorname{j}_0 \left(\sqrt{x^2-2xt}\right) \, .
\end{align}